# Prove that vector is eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a matrix of size $5$ (real values) and real $\lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{2}$, $\lambda_{3}$, such that:

vector $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}$

vector $(1,2,3,4,5)$ is eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_{2}$

vector $(1,3,5,7,9)$ is eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_{3}$

Prove that vector $(43,53,63,73,83)$ is eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $3\lambda_1 + 5\lambda_2 - 7\lambda_3$.

I know that this set of eigenvectors is not lineary independent and I think that this might be important but I don't know how to use this information.

Comment: A selection of eigenvectors from distinct eigenvalues are *always* linearly independent, which is why I'm confident that this exercise is just bogus. Coming up with a counterexample should be straight forward enough, but I'm lazy. :-)

Comment: But it is not mentioned that eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: If the exercise isn't bogus, we at least know that the eigenvalues are not distinct. But I am having a hard time believing that the exercise isn't bogus. Seems too good to be true that we could find a 4th eigenvector and know its eigenvalue just by knowing the other $3$ eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't mind checking, you should (the asker) it is just applying $Ay=\lambda y$

Comment: So let me change my question, in this exercise is it possible that, $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 \neq \lambda_3$ or all eigenvalues must be equal because eigenvectors form lineary dependent set?

Comment: @Berto But, it's not mentioned that they're indistinct either. One could easily construct such a matrix where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are distinct, in order to form a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ be vectors mentioned in exercies(in order).

We have $v_3$ = $2v_2 - v_1$

$A(2v_2 - v_1) = \lambda_3(2v_2 - v_1)$

$2\lambda_2v_2 - \lambda_1v_1 = 2\lambda_3v_2 - \lambda_3v_1$

$v_2(2\lambda_2 - 2\lambda_3) + v_1(\lambda_3 - \lambda_1) = 0$

$\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3$

$3\lambda_1 + 5\lambda_2 -7\lambda_3 = \lambda_1$

$Av_4 = A(av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3)$

$Av_4 = \lambda_1(av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3)$

This is my solution to this problem, because I am almost sure that this exercies is not bogus. If this solution is wrong i would appreciate feedback, if it is right it will be amazing if somebody could tell why counterexample in previous answer is wrong.

Comment: @RichardJensen Can you tell exactly what is wrong with my answer? If your example is indeed correct there have to be something wrong with my solution. "It is wrong, because I found a counter example" is of course correct(if it's in fact counter example) but doesn' tell me why my solution is wrong.

Comment: Because my proof shows that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3$ therefore your counter example must be wrong.

Comment: Deleted my wrong comments, your proof is spot on :).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My counterexample is not a counterexample, and the exercise is correct.

Let $\{(1,1,1,1,1), v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5 \}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$. A linear transformation is uniquely determined by its values on a basis, so let $L$ be the operator which sends $(1,1,1,1,1)$ to itself, and $v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$ to $0$. Let A be the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the above mentioned basis. This $A$ satisfies the conditions of the exercise with $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$.

But then the vector $(43,53,63,73,83)$ has eigenvalue $3$, which is impossible since it is linearly independent of $(1,1,1,1,1)$. So the statement is false.

Comment: I don't see how this transformation is linear. It is not additive for example for vectors $(0,0,0,0,2), (1,1,1,1,-1)$.

Comment: Right, I was messed up a bit. Here is a corrected version of the proof (I'll update OP):

Let $\{ (1,1,1,1,1), v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5 \}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$. A linear transformation is uniquely determined by its values on a basis, so let $L$ be operator which sends $(1,1,1,1,1)$ to itself, and $v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$ to $0$. Let A be the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the above mentioned basis, and follow the proof.

Comment: That's messy you have not given your $A$, as i said the three eigenvalues are indeed equal. Maybe one can prove the existence etc

Comment: @ToniMhax The problem is that I have shown here that there exists a matrix $A$ satisfying the assumptions, and shown that this does not satisfy the conclusion, hence exercise is wrong.

The problem, as I have also written to Bertos solution is that when we conclude that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3$, we reach a contradiction, since this is not always the case, as shown by my example.

Comment: @RichardJensen You say it is linear therefore $A(1,2,3,4,5) =A( \alpha_1(1,1,1,1,1) + \alpha_2v_2 + \dots + \alpha_5v_5) = \alpha_1(1,1,1,1,1)$ For $\alpha_1 \neq 0$ $(1,2,3,4,5)$ is not even eigenvector so your counter example doesn't fit exercise.

Comment: Well damn, you're right! The exercise just looked so wrong, but looking through it again, your own solution is absolutely correct, and my comment on why it is incorrect is nonsense. Downvoting this answer and upvoting yours, and you should flag your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a short hint it is easy to show that $\lambda_3=\lambda_1$, and so $\lambda_2=\dfrac{\lambda_1+\lambda_3}{2}$.
Taking entrywise the first two rows of $Ax_i=\lambda_ix_i$, for $i=1,2,3$.
Proof: $(a_1,\cdots,a_5)$ resp. $(b_1,\cdots,b_5)$ are the first resp. second row of $A$. If $\lambda_1=\lambda_3$ we got that $v_2\in\text{span}\{v_1,v_3\}$ or $\lambda_2=\lambda_1=\lambda_3=\lambda$.

So for the given eigenvectors $Av_1=\lambda_1v_1$ $\implies $ $\sum_{i=1}^5a_i=\sum_{i=1}^5b_i=\lambda_1$. 
$Av_2=\lambda_2v_2$ $\implies$ $\sum_{i=1}^5ia_i=\lambda_2$, $\sum_{i=1}^5ib_i=2\lambda_2$. 
$Av_3=\lambda_3v_3$ $\implies$ 
$\sum_{i=1}^5(2i-1)a_i=\lambda_3$, $\sum_{i=1}^5(2i-1)b_i=3\lambda_3$
so $\lambda_3+\lambda_1=2\lambda_2$
and $3\lambda_3+\lambda_1=4\lambda_2$